# Spring Boot Rest JPA updating data errors

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-restcontroller

Iam sorry, I know that I asked this question before but, got no answers.

I have a problem with updating my database data with Spring rest JPA (PUT Method).

When I do a POST request to insert data, It works perfectly, I have all my data inserted in the right way, however, when I try to update my data with a PUT, the Name is updated event in the database, but not GeometryBasic, I tried to log its value It changes correctly but not in the database, hibernate doesn't persist new values data. 
I have my classes as following:

> Location

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="sw_locations")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Location_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Location_Generator", sequenceName = "Location_Sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private Double longitude;

    @Column(name = "x")
    private Double x;

    @Column(name = "y")
    private Double y;


    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="multi_id") @JsonIgnore
    private MultiBasic multi;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean hasNoPointCoord = (this.getLatitude() ==null && this.getLongitude() == null);
        return  hasNoPointCoord;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Location [point="+this.getX()+" : "+this.getY()+" : "+this.getLatitude() +" : "+ this.getLongitude() + "]";
    }

}
```

> Multi

```
public class Multi extends ArrayList<Location>{
//Some methods
```

}

> Geometry

```
public class Geometry extends ArrayList<Multi>{
    //Some Methods
}
```

> GeometryBasic

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="sw_geometries")
public class GeometryBasic{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Geometry_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Geometry_Generator", sequenceName = "Geometry_Sequence")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="geometry",
               cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<MultiBasic> multies = new ArrayList<MultiBasic>();

    //some other methods
}
```

> MultiBasic

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="sw_multis")
public class MultiBasic{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Multi_Generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Multi_Generator", sequenceName = "Multi_Sequence")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="geometry_id") @JsonIgnore
    private GeometryBasic geometry;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="multi",
               cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

}
```

> GeometryHelper

```
public class GeometryHelper {

     public static Geometry map(GeometryBasic geom) {


         //Check if geometry object is defined and contains multies
        if(geom == null || geom.isEmpty())
            return null;

        Geometry geometry = new Geometry();

        //Map nested collections into 2D Array.
        geom.getMulties().forEach(m->{
            Multi multi  = new Multi();
            multi.addAll(m.getLocations());
            geometry.add(multi);
        });

        return geometry;
    }

     public static GeometryBasic mapToBasic (Geometry geom) {


         //Check if geometry object is defined and contains multies
        if(geom == null)
                return null;
        GeometryBasic geometry = new GeometryBasic();
        List<MultiBasic> multis = new ArrayList<MultiBasic>();

        //Iterate over multis to add link to geometry 
        geom.forEach(m ->{
            MultiBasic multi = new MultiBasic();
            List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

            //iterate over locations to add link to Multi
            m.forEach( l -> {
                l.setMulti(multi);
                locations.add(l);
            });

            multi.setLocations(locations);
            multi.setGeometry(geometry);
            multis.add(multi);
        });

        geometry.setMulties(multis);

        return geometry;
     }

}
```

> Class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntityWithNameTitleLocation extends AbstractEntityWithNameTitle {

    @Column(name="entity_name")
    private String name;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "id_geometry")  @JsonIgnore
    private GeometryBasic geometryBasic;

    public GeometryBasic getGeometryBasic() {
        return this.geometryBasic;
    }

    public void setBasicGeometry(GeometryBasic geometry) {
        this.geometryBasic = geometry;
    }

    @Transient
    Geometry geometry;

    //Return the transformed object basic geometry
    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return GeometryHelper.map(this.geometryBasic);
    }

    //Return the transformed object basic geometry
    public void setGeometry(Geometry geom) {
        this.setBasicGeometry(GeometryHelper.mapToBasic(geom));
    }
}
```

> ```
> Object :
> ```

```
 "geometry":[[{"x":-170341.70902636572,"y":5977585.216564284,"longitude":-1.5302056074142456,"latitude":47.217116005214564}]]
```

Comment: OK.  So that's the data model.  It would be useful to see an example object that fails to update.

Comment: {"name":"somename","geometry":[[{"x":-170341.70902636572,"y":5977585.216564284,"longitude":-1.5302056074142456,"latitude":47.217116005214564}]]}

Comment: If I send and object like that as a create; it is created, but if I send another one with different coordinates, it doesn't nothing, they don't change